# How to work with Decision Table with WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have to work on decision table using wso2 and my requirement is like that i should be able to modify the data dynamically in the decision table.
is it possible to achieve this requirement using wso2 ?Please suggest me.

Comment: as far as I Know the  excel file are inside .aar file, so any time you modify the excel the service is reloaded by the server

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Rule Service Project inside of WSO2 Developer Studio, and use an excel document as your rule source. When you build your service with maven command "mvn clean install" the excel file are stored inside the .aar file.

At this point, any time you modify your excel inside the service, the service will be redeployed.
Please check this link for more information: http://desarrollosoa.blogspot.com/2015/12/wso2-brs-uso-de-tablas-de-decision-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dynamically update decision tables. for that, you have to store decision tables in registry and refer it within the rule service package (.aar). when you update the decision table in the registry, the rule service get redeployed with new updates.

Refer [1] for screencast of using decision tables with WSO2 BRS

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-D2Hgdrzs8

Thanks,
Mili